# MERGE Query running very slow in Management Studio 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I've got a pretty simple MERGE query where the source table is only about 41MB and the target table is about 4GB. I'm basically just adding row entries to the larger target table (while avoiding duplicate primary key entries). This query runs very slow when executed in Management studio. It's already run 15mins and not completed. Just wondering if there are any options for speeding up execution or if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks.

Here's the query:

```
MERGE [myschema].[targettable] target
USING [myschema].[sourcetable] source
ON target.STATION_ID = source.STATION_ID    
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN    
  INSERT (STATION_ID, SENSORNAME, TIME_TAG, ORIG_VALUE, ED_VALUE, SOURCE)    
  VALUES (source.STATION_ID, source.SENSORNAME, source.TIME_TAG, source.ORIG_VALUE, source.ED_VALUE, source.SOURCE);
```

Beginning of estimated execution xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.1600.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="92529300000" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="45530500" StatementText="--sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;&#xD;&#xA;--RECONFIGURE;&#xD;&#xA;--GO&#xD;&#xA;--sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;&#xD;&#xA;--RECONFIGURE;&#xD;&#xA;--GO&#xD;&#xA;MERGE XCManager.XC_DATA1 target&#xD;&#xA;USING XCManager.FrkFalls_FORMATTED source&#xD;&#xA;ON target.STATION_ID = source.STATION_ID&#xD;&#xA;WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN&#xD;&#xA;  INSERT (STATION_ID, SENSORNAME, TIME_TAG, ORIG_VALUE, ED_VALUE, SOURCE)&#xD;&#xA;  VALUES (source.STATION_ID, source.SENSORNAME, source.TIME_TAG, source.ORIG_VALUE, source.ED_VALUE, source.SOURCE);" StatementType="MERGE" QueryHash="0x0A5DB292FF222BCD" QueryPlanHash="0x1FBBCC92AE041A3E">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="64" CompileTime="31" CompileCPU="15" CompileMemory="736">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="92529.3" EstimateIO="7070610" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="92529300000" LogicalOp="Merge" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Merge" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="45530500">
              <OutputList />
              <Update WithOrderedPrefetch="true" DMLRequestSort="true">
                <Object Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Index="[DAT1_PK]" Alias="[target]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                <SetPredicate>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[SOURCE] as [target].[SOURCE] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([Expr1008]),[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[SENSORNAME] as [target].[SENSORNAME] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([Expr1009]),[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[ED_VALUE] as [target].[ED_VALUE] = [XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[FrkFalls_FORMATTED].[ED_VALUE] as [source].[ED_VALUE],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[ORIG_VALUE] as [target].[ORIG_VALUE] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[FrkFalls_FORMATTED].[ORIG_VALUE] as [source].[ORIG_VALUE]),[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[TIME_TAG] as [target].[TIME_TAG] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[FrkFalls_FORMATTED].[TIME_TAG] as [source].[TIME_TAG]),[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[STATION_ID] as [target].[STATION_ID] = RaiseIfNullUpdate([Expr1010]),[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[FLAG1] as [target].[FLAG1] = [Expr1011],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[FLAG2] as [target].[FLAG2] = [Expr1012],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[FLAG3] as [target].[FLAG3] = [Expr1013],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[FLAG4] as [target].[FLAG4] = [Expr1014],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[HIGH_HIGH_FLAG] as [target].[HIGH_HIGH_FLAG] = [Expr1015],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[HIGH_FLAG] as [target].[HIGH_FLAG] = [Expr1016],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[LOW_FLAG] as [target].[LOW_FLAG] = [Expr1017],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[LOW_LOW_FLAG] as [target].[LOW_LOW_FLAG] = [Expr1018],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[ROC_FLAG] as [target].[ROC_FLAG] = [Expr1019],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[NO_CHG_FLAG] as [target].[NO_CHG_FLAG] = [Expr1020],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[ALARM_FLAG] as [target].[ALARM_FLAG] = [Expr1021],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[STD_DEV_FLAG] as [target].[STD_DEV_FLAG] = [Expr1022],[XConnectDB_NHDES].[XCManager].[XC_DATA1].[AVG_FLAG] as [target].[AVG_FLAG] = [Expr1023]">
                    <ScalarExpressionList>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <MultipleAssign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="SOURCE" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Intrinsic>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="SENSORNAME" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Intrinsic>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="ED_VALUE" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[FrkFalls_FORMATTED]" Alias="[source]" Column="ED_VALUE" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="ORIG_VALUE" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[FrkFalls_FORMATTED]" Alias="[source]" Column="ORIG_VALUE" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Intrinsic>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="TIME_TAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[FrkFalls_FORMATTED]" Alias="[source]" Column="TIME_TAG" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Intrinsic>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="STATION_ID" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Intrinsic FunctionName="RaiseIfNullUpdate">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1010" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Intrinsic>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="FLAG1" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1011" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="FLAG2" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1012" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="FLAG3" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1013" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="FLAG4" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1014" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="HIGH_HIGH_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1015" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="HIGH_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1016" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="LOW_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1017" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="LOW_LOW_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1018" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="ROC_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1019" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="NO_CHG_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1020" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="ALARM_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1021" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="STD_DEV_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1022" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                          <Assign>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[XConnectDB_NHDES]" Schema="[XCManager]" Table="[XC_DATA1]" Alias="[target]" Column="AVG_FLAG" />
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1023" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Assign>
                        </MultipleAssign>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </ScalarExpressionList>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </SetPredicate>
                <ActionColumn>
                  <ColumnReference Column="Action1007" />
                </ActionColumn>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="130" EstimateCPU="9252.93" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="92529300000" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="38367300">
                  <OutputList>
```

Comment: Is there an index on target.STATION_ID?

Comment: There is a clustered index of my four primary key columns. STATION_ID, SENSORNAME, TIME_TAG, & SOURCE.

Comment: Why are you using merge for that? Why not a straight insert since you are not specifying either an update or delete action? HOw many records are you expecting to insert?

Comment: Is STATION_ID the first column of the composite index?

Comment: I'm using MERGE because it allows me to skip duplicate entries that violate my primary key constraints (WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET). Basically the data overlaps and I just want to add "new" entries from the source table. I expect about 670k rows to be added for this particular table but possibly more in other source tables I eventually want to add to target table.

Comment: No, STATION_ID is 3rd in order. Will that affect performance? I also just noticed that my index total fragmentation is about 72%. Could this be a problem as well?

Comment: If STATION_ID isn't the first column in your index, you will likely be scanning.  Can you post your execution plan XML?

Comment: Posted execution xml above but couldn't fit the whole thing. I tried rebuilding the clustered index to have STATION_ID first but query still takes forever.

Comment: @user1148229 - Can you post the whole plan? You can paste it up to [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for example. Though looks like if you just add a non clustered index on `target.STATION_ID` that should speed things up anyway.

Comment: Tried adding a new index for target.STATION_ID but still very slow. New XML execution plan (with new index) is here: https://gist.github.com/1635832

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the new index you have added isn't that helpful as `STATION_ID` has different datatypes bewteeen the two tables and it needs to do an implicit cast to `nvarchar(20)`.

If possible make these consistent.

The `MERGE` version essentially does something like

```
INSERT INTO FrkFalls_FORMATTED
SELECT *
FROM XC_DATA1 source
LEFT JOIN FrkFalls_FORMATTED target
ON target.STATION_ID = source.STATION_ID
WHERE target.STATION_ID IS NULL
```

As `STATION_ID` is not unique this could potentially mean that it ends up joining then discarding a whole load of intermediate records that don't contribute to the final result. The estimated plan you have uploaded shows 92 billion rows coming out of the Many-to-Many `MERGE LEFT JOIN`. These figures are probably woefully wrong but you haven't supplied the more informative actual execution plan.

[image: Plan]

You could try abandoning Merge and rewriting as

```
INSERT INTO FrkFalls_FORMATTED
SELECT *
FROM XC_DATA1 source
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM FrkFalls_FORMATTED target 
                  WHERE target.STATION_ID = source.STATION_ID)
```

Which may well be more efficient.

Comment: Also tried query above, but got duplicate key error: **Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'XCManager.XC_DATA1' with unique index 'DAT1_PK'.
The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Ah! Think I have it. Turned off Unique in index 'DAT1_PK'. Then query ran successfully and only inserted new rows from source table. Thanks again for everybody's help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually turns out my original solution of turning off Unique in index is not so good. The legacy data I was trying to import was filled with a lot of non-unique rows. This made it impossible for me to turn unique back on after import.

I ended up having to do a little more fancy query using a temp table 'q' to account for this. This query first selects all distinct rows from source table (based on fields TIME_TAG, STATION_ID, and SENSORNAME) and then inserts these into target table as long as it is not a duplicate row (again based on fields TIME_TAG, STATION_ID, and SENSORNAME).

```
    ;WITH    q AS
            (
            SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TIME_TAG, STATION_ID, SENSORNAME ORDER BY TIME_TAG) rn
            FROM    XConnectDB_NHDES.XCManager.Lakeport_FORMATTED
            )


    INSERT INTO XConnectDB_NHDES.XCManager.XC_DATA1
    SELECT STATION_ID, SENSORNAME, TIME_TAG, SOURCE, ORIG_VALUE, ED_VALUE, FLAG1, FLAG2, FLAG3, FLAG4, HIGH_HIGH_FLAG, HIGH_FLAG, LOW_FLAG, LOW_LOW_FLAG, ROC_FLAG, NO_CHG_FLAG, ALARM_FLAG, STD_DEV_FLAG, AVG_FLAG 
    FROM q source 
    WHERE rn = 1 and
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM XConnectDB_NHDES.XCManager.XC_DATA1 target 
                      WHERE target.TIME_TAG = source.TIME_TAG and 
                      target.STATION_ID = source.STATION_ID and
                      target.SENSORNAME = source.SENSORNAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've probably finished inserting the data, but for the future, I think this query would be faster:

```
INSERT INTO Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster
SELECT * FROM Test.CoveredIndexTestSubset
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster;
```

The EXCEPT operator returns all rows from the left table (Test.CoveredIndexTestSubset) that are not in the right table (Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster) and in this case, they are then inserted into Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster. (The tables have the same structure of course.)

Though I did not have the time to setup a test that exactly duplicates your situation, I can tell you this. Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster had about 900K rows and Test.CoveredIndexTestSubset had about 206K rows. There were just over 3K rows in Subset that were not in Master.

The above query took 14 seconds to run.

Neither table is indexed. The table have 2 columns. An int and a varchar. There are dublicate rows in both tables.

So, your milage will vary, but I would be interested in hearing your results.

This is an updated query based on Martin's input:

```
INSERT INTO Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster 
SELECT * 
FROM Test.CoveredIndexTestSubset 
WHERE Col1 IN ( SELECT col1 FROM Test.CoveredIndexTestSubset 
                   EXCEPT 
                   SELECT col1 FROM Test.CoveredIndexTestMaster )
```

This took 20 seconds to run.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing. This compares the whole row not just the `STATION_ID` values.

Comment: Right. If there's a duplicate primary key in subset and master but with different details, then it would be returned by the except operator and fail the insert.  I updated the query in my original answer.

Comment: I appreciate all the help guys. I'm still having issues with this. When I tried the first EXCEPT query in this form: Insert into XConnectDB_NHDES.XCManager.XC_DATA1
Select * from XConnectDB_NHDES.XCManager.FrkFalls_FORMATTED
execpt
select * from XConnectDB_NHDES.XCManager.XC_DATA1 as target
where target.STATION_ID = 'FFDN3'

Comment: above query gave me duplicate row errors. Then tried last query with WHERE Col1 IN ... This ran and completed but with 0 rows affected. The issue is that I have to compare 2 Cols (STATION_ID and TIME_TAG) to determine if it is a duplicate row. This query would not accept 2 Cols or * in the SELECT EXCEPT SELECT statements at end of query.